# Spring @Transactional behavior calling both Transactional and Non-Transactional Methods

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I'm looking at some existing code and wanted to know what happen's in the following scenario with Spring's @Transactional annotation?  Consider the following example:

A POST request hits a @Controller annotated with @Transactional:

```
@ResponseBody
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value="/send", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void send(@RequestBody Response response) {          
    try {
        DBItem updatedDbItem = repository.updateResponse(response);
        if (updatedDbItem == null){
            //some logging
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {         
        //some logging
    }
}
```

The controller calls a non @transactional repository method which sets a value and in turns calls a another @Transactional method:

```
@Override
public DBItem updateResponse(Response response) {
    try {
        DBItem dBItem = findResponseById(response.getKey());            
        if (dBItem != null){
            dBItem.setSomeField(response.getValue());               
            return updateDataBaseItem(response);
        }               
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //some logging          
    }
    return null;
}
```

The following updateDataBaseItem() method is common and called from other non transactional methods as well as the above method:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public DBItem updateDataBaseItem(Response response){
    try {           
        DBItem dBItem = em.merge(response);                     
        return dBItem;  
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //some logging          
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `send()` => spring detect @transaction with default parameters
             actually Propagation setting is REQUIRED and the spring join the exist transaction or create new if none.
2. `repository.updateResponse(..)` => No transactions params the method execute within the same transaction already exist
3. `updateDataBaseItem(..)` => calling the method in same repository , spring will not recognize the @Transaction annotation because the use of proxy mode, so this method will be executed within the same transaction

> a method within the target object calling another method of the target
>   object, will not lead to an actual transaction at runtime even if the
>   invoked method is marked with @Transactional